# How to put a number before ListView item in Android

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

In my list the data is shown like this,

```
test 1
test 2
test 3
```

But I want to show them like,

```
1) test 1
2) test 2
3) test 3
```

How can I do that. Plese help. This is the code I have done so far.

```
public class AppointmentList extends Activity{

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.select_to_delete);

        String[] myStringArray = new String[] { "test 1", "test 2", "test 3"};

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myStringArray);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

Comment: Just change "test 1" to "1) test 1" and so on, if this approach suits you.

Comment: can't. the data for array is going to be come from a database.

Comment: if this approach do not suits you, you must create a custom adapter to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should make your own Custom Adapter Class and implement its methods . . .

Here is the whole example of Custom Adapter class :

```
 private class Adapter extends BaseAdapter {
            private ArrayList<String> array;
            private Context ctx;

            public Adapter(Context ctx) {
                this.ctx = ctx;
                array = new ArrayList<String>();
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return this.array.size();
            }

            @Override
            public Object getItem(int position) {
                return this.array.get(position);
            }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(int position) {
                return position;
            }

            /**
             * add a String Item in a List
             * 
             * @param item
             */
            public void addItem(String item) {
                this.array.add(item);
                this.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            /**
             * Delete an Item from a List
             * 
             * @param position
             */
            public void deleteItem(int position) {
                this.array.remove(position);
                this.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View newView;

                if (convertView == null) {
                    newView = View.inflate(ctx, R.layout.item_layout, null);
                } else {
                    newView = convertView;
                }

                String txt = (String) this.getItem(position);

//   Here is what you're looking for:
                ((TextView) newView.findViewById(R.id.item_numb)).setText(""
                        + (position + 1) + ". ");
//   End;
                ((TextView) newView.findViewById(R.id.item_text)).setText(txt);

                return newView;
            }

        }
```

You can use Adapter afterwards like this :

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_to_do_list);

        ListView ls = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        Adapter adapter = new Adapter(this);
        ls.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Comment: but how can i use this with a adapter

Comment: You can check this link too, 2.1 ch.
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterown_custom

Answer (score 2):

You would need to create a custom `ArrayAdapter` to populate a `ListView` from your objects the way you want.

The advantage of this technic is that you gain a Views recycle mechanism that will recycle the `Views` inside you `ListView` in order to spend less memory.

**In Short** you would have to:

**1.** Create  an object that represents your data for a single row.

**2.** Create an `ArrayList` of those objects.

**3.** Create a layout that contains a ListView or add a ListView to you main layout using code.

**4.** Create a layout of a single row.

**5.** Create a `ViewHolder` that will represent the visual aspect of you data row from the stand point of `Views`.

**6.** Create a custom `ArrayAdapter` that will populate the rows according to you needs, in it you will override the `getView` method and use the `position` parameter you receive for the corrent row `View` to indicate the row `index`.

**7.** Finally assign this `ArrayAdapter` to your `ListView` in `onCreate`.

You can get an idea of how to implement this by reading this blog post I wrote:

[Create a Custom ArrayAdapter](http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=495)

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to create a custom adapter and use the `position+1` as the number in your row

Answer (score 0):

You can try to display html content on your list

for example :

```
Html.fromHtml("<ol><li> test 1</li></ol>")
```

[Html Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml(java.lang.String))